Can you figure out how to align the top of the <p> tag with the top of the <textarea> tag?
I’m trying to create a text box in the style of a source code editor, but I’m using the <p> tag for the number side bar thing, and the <textarea> tag for the source code, so they do

I'm pretty sure the problem occurs for all cases, but here's the code:


<link href="https://www.fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source%20Code%20Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<p style=" font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; color: #a9a9a9; background-color: #4f4f4f; width: 12px; height: 360px; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; float: left;">1</p>
<textarea style=" font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; resize: none; width: 472px; height: 360px; color: white; resize: none; background-color: black; border-radius: 0; float: left;"></textarea>




In your code you need to apply margin: 0; padding: 0; to p tag.
The extra margin on p tag is the default css.
To remove default css styles from all element you need to add
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

which I have added in following example.
Apart from this you are encouraged to go through different layout techniques like flexbox and grid.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  width: 12px;
  height: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
}

textarea {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  resize: none;
  width: 472px;
  height: 360px;
  color: white;
  resize: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  float: left;
}
<link href="https://www.fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source%20Code%20Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<p>1</p>
<textarea></textarea>




You're using a <p> but the P element comes with lots of built-in style properties to make text look "good" (that even will vary between browsers). This default styling is what is causing the improper alignment.
It's much better to use a <div> instead, which has no default styling.
If we do that, and also set padding and border to 0 for the textarea, then it will align:


<div style=" font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; color: #a9a9a9; background-color: #4f4f4f; width: 12px; height: 360px; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; float: left;">1</div>
<textarea style=" font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; resize: none; width: 472px; height: 360px; color: white; resize: none; background-color: black; border-radius: 0; float: left; padding: 0; border: 0"></textarea>    




Place the <textarea> within a <li> of an <ol>. Not only is it perfectly semantic, the number is added automatically. There are just one simple adjustment to the CSS of the <textarea> in order to line-up the numbers correctly. If you don't want <textarea> to resize just remove overflow: hidden.
textarea {
  display: table;
  ...
}



textarea {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li + li {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}
<ol>
  <li>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </li>
</ol>




I believe you need to dive into flex css, this is go-to approach to align children objects in parent object
CSS Flexbox

Though your suggestion is good but it is not related to the question asked.  The problem is not related to layout.
